# Sylow, Suzuki group and solvability of finite groups

Tags: lie-groups, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

I read this theorem in the article which Antonio Beltran, I don't understand why prove this theorem:

"we can easily prove (by **induction** on the **order**) that if a group G satisfies $ν_3(G)=1$ and *has no composition factor* isomorphic to the simple group $Sz(q)$, then $G$ is solvable."

(which $ν_p(G)$ be the number of Sylow $p−$subgroups of $G$, and the only non-abelian simple finite groups whose order is not divisible by 3 are the Suzuki simple groups, $Sz(q)$, with $q=2^r$ and $r > 1$ odd).

I would be very thankful if you showed me ideas to prove by induction.

Comment: Just consider the possible composition factors. You don’t need to induct.

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to ask this problem again. If P is a 3-subgroup Sylow , then  P⊴G, and P is solvable. Then I don't understand "G/P has a non-abelian simple composition factor H ?". I'm not sure this.